# GridLayout look good in design and emulator but not on the device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have strange problem with GridLayout. In design, and emulator it works just fine, but when tried on real device it is all stretched.

I tried to copy XAML to a new project, where minimum version is API26, but same thing is happening, altought sometimes it does stretch image differently.
I tested this with 3 different devices, and it is same on all of them (all devices was API 26).

I really don't know where i messed up, so if anybody have an idea.

**Design and Emulator** - Everything is fine

[image: Design and Emulator view]

**Device** - looks like first button  in every row is stretched

[image: Device]

**Device after copy and paste into new project (API 26)** - looks like just first button is stretched

[image]

My XAML

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="5"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Operater"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"

        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="back"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn6"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn8"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="res"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn9"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn10"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn11"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn12"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="last"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn13"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn14"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn15"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn16"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="send"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn17"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn18"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn19"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn20"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="up"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn21"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn22"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn23"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn24"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOption6"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="down"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Button you must have `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` otherwise it won't run, but that size must be 0dp, and it will work on devices, at least in my case.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/orderBtn1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="B1"/>
```

Comment: I can't for the next 2 days... but i will.